# Passing an "extractor" to a C++ method that also takes an iterable

Tags: c++, templates, std

I wrote a utility function that allows me to write the elements of a `std::vector` to a `std::ostream` separated by a delimiter. *(I know there's another question about achieving this end, but this question is about why my implementation doesn't work.)*

```
template<typename I, typename S>
struct Joiner {
    const I &iterable;
    const S &separator;
};

template<typename I, typename S>
inline auto join(const I &iterable, const S &separator) -> const Joiner<I, S> {
    return Joiner<I, S>{iterable, separator};
}

template<typename I, typename S>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Joiner<I, S> &joiner) {
    auto i = joiner.iterable.begin();
    auto end = joiner.iterable.end();
    if (i != end) {
        stream << *i++;
        while (i != end) {
            stream << joiner.separator << *i++;
        }
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Nothing unusual here.

But sometimes what's in the `vector` isn't the thing I want to output. For example it might be a `vector<int *>` and I want to output the `int` values, not the pointers.

So I thought, instead of assuming that the value to print is `*i`, let's pass in an "extractor" so that, in the case of the `vector<int *>` I could specify `**i`.

I've tried to do this a couple of ways and it's not really coming together. My current thinking is that template parameter `X` is the eXtracted type, and the `join` method should take a `std::function` that returns that type. The type of the extractor function's parameter would be `I::iterator`.

```
template<typename I, typename S, typename X>
struct Joiner {
    const I &iterable;
    const S &separator;
    const std::function<X(typename I::iterator)> extract;
};

template<typename I, typename S, typename X>
inline auto join(const I &iterable, const S &separator, std::function<X(typename I::iterator)> extract) -> const Joiner<I, S, X> {
    return Joiner<I, S, X>{iterable, separator, extract};
}
```

And then, in the `operator <<` implementation, I use `joiner.extract(i++)` instead of `*i++`.

However, this doesn't work. I wrote this test program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 25;
    std::vector<int *> v{&a, &b, &c};
    std::cout << join<std::vector<int *>, std::string, int>(v, ",", [](std::vector<int *>::iterator i) { return **i; }) << std::endl;
}
```

When compiling it I get errors like this:

```
/Users/wboyce/git/mathias/util.hpp:31:19: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::function<int (typename vector<int *, allocator<int *> >::iterator)>' (aka 'const function<int (__wrap_iter<int **>)>')
    stream << joiner.extract(i++);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/wboyce/git/mathias/scratch.cpp:19:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<std::__1::vector<int *, std::__1::allocator<int *> >, std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>' requested here
    std::cout << join<std::vector<int *>, std::string, int>(v, ",", [](const std::vector<int *>::iterator i) { return **i; }) << std::endl;
              ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:2255:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '__wrap_iter<int *const *>' to '__wrap_iter<int **>' for 1st argument
    _Rp operator()(_ArgTypes...) const;
```

I think the source of my trouble is that the iterable type is `I` but I'm using it at `const I &` which means that the iterator is going to be returning something like `const I::iterator` but here's where things get fuzzy for me.

- I don't think that the iterator type is really `const I::iterator` because that is a const iterator over `I` not a non-const iterator over `const I`.
- Does that mean the iterator is going to be returning `const X` or should the constness be baked into `X`?
- Can the compiler be made to infer the type arguments to `join` so I don't have to specify them?
- What else do I need to do to make this work?

And is this even the right approach? I initially thought that `X` would be the type of the extractor function itself... but I couldn't make that work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason (or one of the primary reasons) to use `std::function` is when type erasure is required.

There is no need for type erasure here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename I, typename S, typename E>
struct Joiner {
    const I &iterable;
    const S &separator;
    E e;
};

template<typename I, typename S, typename E>
inline auto join(const I &iterable, const S &separator,
         E &&e) -> const Joiner<I, S, E> {
    return Joiner<I, S, E>{iterable, separator, std::forward<E>(e)};
}

template<typename I, typename S, typename E>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Joiner<I, S, E> &joiner) {
    auto i = joiner.iterable.begin();
    auto end = joiner.iterable.end();
    if (i != end) {
        stream << joiner.e(*i++);
        while (i != end) {
            stream << joiner.separator << joiner.e(*i++);
        }
    }
    return stream;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 25;
    std::vector<int *> v{&a, &b, &c};

    std::cout << join(v, ",", [](int *p) { return *p; }) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: This works, but I wanted the extractor to accept the iterator type (the type of `i` in `operator <<`), so the extractor would be called as `joiner.extract(i++)`. How would I have to define the lambda in that case?

Comment: The iterator would simply take an `std::vector<int *>::iterator` parameter, but also all invocations of would be `joiner.e(i++)`, instead.

Comment: A-ha, it's `std::vector<int *>::const_iterator`!

Comment: Or that, instead.

Comment: Thank you! I think my failure to remember `const_iterator` led me down a rabbit hole.

Comment: If at least `C++14` is available, you can simply declare the lambda as ` [](auto p) { return **p; }` and the compiler will figure it out all by itself.

Comment: I tried that originally, but I declared it as `auto &p` (with reference) and clang threw up all over it.

Comment: Because you are passing a temporary, you needed `const auto &`.